# Android Device Communication in Kivy/Python

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm interested in implementing some local multiplayer into a game I am working on in my free time. Does Kivy or any other Python package allow for device-to-device communication (on android)? In my game I want to create a system where one player creates and hosts the game and other players join via wifi.

Comment: Investigate "UDP broadcast" or Bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I need to use Python's socket library.